# How to create pull to refresh feature in windowsphone Pivot?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, pivotviewer

I am making an rss App where I'd like to include the pull to refresh feature on a pivot item instead of a separate refresh button. I tried different Mouse Event Handlers but they dont work right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use RadDataBoundListBox from Telerik with PivotItem

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Title" Foreground="Black">
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerikListBox:PullToRefreshIndicatorControl">
           <Setter Property="RefreshTimeLabelFormat" Value="last refresh time:{0:H:mm}"/>
        </Style>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

Also I recommend you download Telerik WP controls on your phone http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx#Demo

Comment: Nice but no practical use unless you buy the whole suite. Shows constant purchase Alert.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple control that implements the "Pull to refresh" feature, and the "Load data on demand", you can find it in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedListview), read about it from [this blog post](http://www.tareqateik.com/extendedlistview-control-for-universal-apps-pull-to-refresh-load-more-data-on-demand). Works on both Windows 8 & Windows Phone 8.1

[image]

Comment: Hey seems like a nice package but can you make it a level down and allow windowsphone-8 also.